# terminal input not appearing

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time

class terminal(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.prompt()


    def prompt(self):
        x = True
        while x:
            command = raw_input()
            x = self.interpret(command)

    def interpret(self,command):
        if command == 'exit':
            #_conf.cancel()
            #_conf.allclear.wait()
            return False
        else:
            print 'Invalid Command'
        return True

command = 'java -jar ../bukkit/craftbukkit.jar'
#startcmd = 'java -Xmx' + str(self.config['start_heap']) + 'M -Xms' + str(self.config['max_heap'])  + 'M -jar ' + str(path)
#stopcmd = 'screen -S ' + self.config['screen_bukkit'] + ' -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "stop\r"`"'
term = terminal()
term.start()
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while (p.poll() == None):
    line = p.stderr.readline()
    if not line: break
    print line.strip()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This is my simplified code. Runs with no errors however when typing for raw_input() in the terminal class nothing I type appears at the prompt. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` takes the prompt text as a parameter, and defaults to an empty string. Try changing it to `raw_input("input: ")` or something like that.

Comment: Even though thats one less thing i'll have to look up thats not the problem. Its not that theres no prompt its that what i type doesnt appear